# Setting focus to listviews in the tabcontrol of a winform

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, tabcontrol

In my project, in a form there are two list views in the tabcontrol, i am unable to set the focus to both the list view items. I am using the following code. The problem is that I am able to select only one listview among the both. Please tell me what is the alternative I can do to select both the listviews in the form.

```
    private void tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BindData1();
        if (listViewClients.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            listViewClients.Items[0].Selected = true;
            listViewClients.Select();
        }

        if (listView1.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            listView1.Items[0].Selected = true;
            listView1.Select();
        }   
    }
```

Comment: you cannot  focus two controls at the same time

Comment: Yes, only one control can have the focus. This is the standard, and it is what's expected by the users who use your program. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: oops,, In the tab control the two tabs are for "Delete" and "Update", there are two listview controls for the different operations. That is why I need to set focus to both the listviews. However thanks, I will try to use the one listview in the both the tabs.  --Thank you.

Comment: @karthikreddy it's still unclear on **why** you want such a strange behavior which is **impossible**. Do you mean you want your ListViewItem to look like focused even when it's not focused?

Comment: Eureka.. I got the solution. Thank you guys for the comments.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BindData1();
        switch (this.tabControl1.SelectedTab.Name)
        {
            case "tpUpdate":
                 listViewClients.Items[0].Selected = true;
                 listViewClients.Select();
                  break;

                  case "tpDelete":
                  listView1.Items[0].Selected = true;
            listView1.Select();
               break;                     
        }                      
    }
```